# DIV layout with scrolling and left/right areas

Tags: html, css, layout, scrollbar

I'd like to achieve the following layout:

[image]

The scrolling is easy, it's just a nested DIVs. I also know how to add the left 40px area. The question is: how to add the right 40px area? Note that both 40px areas are outside of the scrolling space.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about separate divs for the 40px portions, as the divider line seems to indicate they're separate in the image. If they were separate you could easily set their width and display: inline-block to make the line up properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the **Flexbox**:

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {width:100%}

.parent {
  display: flex; /* displays the children inline */
}

.parent > .child {
  height: 100px;
}

.parent > .child:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 1; /* stretches to fill the remaining space */
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.parent > .child:nth-child(2) > div {
  width: 2000px;
}

.parent > .child:first-child,
.parent > .child:nth-child(3) {
  width: 40px;
  background: Lavender;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child">
    <div>...WIDE DIV INSIDE THE SECOND CHILD...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```